# Running Nvidia GPUs for experiments and intel integrated graphics for display on Linux

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, pci

I am currently using a Lenovo Thinkstation P330 with an nvidia GPU & intel integrated graphics. Their BIOS currently seems to let me select ONLY intel OR nvidia. In either configuration, running lspci only shows one VGA controller so my guess is that the bios hides the GPU in some way? For this reason, I think I can't use prior questions on this topic of running both integrated and dedicated gpus. I would like a config where I use intel for my display but run CUDA experiments on the nvidia gpu ultimately.

My approach thus far: I have tried using lspci and setpci to change the config space so that perhaps the kernel could recognize the device. My Nvidia GPU always shows up on "1@00:0.0" while my intel one always shows up at "0@00:02.0". I tried to modify lspci and setpci sources to force fully write to the config space with direct hardware access even if it doesn't find a proper vendor but it didn't work.

Any idea if this is even possible? I guess a different BIOS might do the trick but I would prefer not changing the bios.
I am running Fedora 33 if it helps.

Comment: Not sure it is the same thing  you need cause you are on fedora and the bios step makes me think it is not doable but there is optimus swtich to manage multiple gpus: https://github.com/dglt1/optimus-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the video settings in the BIOS to Auto. You may need to update your BIOS first. You should then see both video devices in `lspci`.